# Code working fine as long as not saved

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am recently facing a strange issue with my code in earth-engine. The moment i save it, it stops working and gives me a simple error of blahblah is not a funtion. But the same code works just fine as long as it is not saved.
Has someone else encountered the same issue? and if yes, then how did you overcome it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Firefox. Sometimes Firefox doesn't support it.
Apparently this error can be avoided using Chrome.

Or you get the link and reload the whole page.

Comment: I am already using chrome and the get link trick worked like a charm for me, albeit only one time, but i still count this as a victory.

Thanks alot indeed.

Comment: Okay i take back the earlier remark about it working like a charm. The charm has vanished and once again the script is making my head spin with its insane error .